# using ripgrep to find adjacent word

Tags: grep, ripgrep

How to use ripgrep to find adjacent duplicated words.
for example

```
one hello hello world
```

How to locate `hello hello` by using ripgrep?

### Solved

```
rg  '(hello)[[:blank:]]+\1' --pcre2  <<<'one hello hello world'
```

Comment: what do you mean by adjacent? two words next to each other which are same? do you have to use ripgrep?

Comment: My mistake. adjacent duplicated word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use GNU grep too (for the [Back-reference extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html)):

```
grep -E '(hello)[[:blank:]]+\1' <<<'one hello hello world'
```

for the portability you could use:

```
grep '\(hello\)[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*\1'
```

add `-w` if you want to match on word boundaries instead;

---

From the [man grep](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html):

> **Back-references and Subexpressions**
> The back-reference \n, where n is a single  digit,  matches  the  substring  previously  matched  by  the  nth
> parenthesized subexpression of the regular expression.

Comment: What's the \1 for ? I see it prevents matching single hello but how does it work, can you give more details ?

Comment: Back-references are not standard in extended regular expressions (believe it or not), although GNU `grep` may support them (`-E` is not standard either, after all).

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution with awk:

```
{
    for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i == $(i+1)) {
            printf("%s %s\n", $i,$(i+1));
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

This will only search for pairs of 2 same words - for example:
word word word -> word word (one pair)
word word word word -> word word word word (two pairs)

If you want to count the number of adjacent same words in each line:

```
{
    for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) {
        counter = 1;
        while ($i == $(i+1)) {
            counter++;
            i++;
        }
        if (counter > 1) {
            printf("%d %s %d\n", NR,$i,counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f awk_script your_file
```

Comment: yes, but then it would match two pairs in a sequence of 3 words

Comment: No, because that way you only check if odd words are followed by the same word. It wouldn't match blah word word blah :)